# Alter string to enum

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I am using the method below to change the column type from string to enum. Is there an alternative way to do this?

Is it possible to use it as a knex.raw to form such query?

```sql
CREATE TYPE type AS ENUM ('disabled', 'include', 'exclude');
    ALTER TABLE test_table ALTER COLUMN test_col DROP DEFAULT;
    ALTER TABLE test_table ALTER COLUMN test_col TYPE logic USING(test_col::type), ALTER COLUMN test_col SET DEFAULT 'disabled'::logic;
```

```js
return schema
  .table('offers', function (table) {
    cols.forEach(function (column) {
      table.renameColumn(column, column + '_old');
    });
  })
  .then(function () {
    var schema = knex.schema;

    return schema.table('offers', function (table) {
      cols.forEach(function (column) {
        table.enum(column, ['disabled', 'include', 'exclude']).defaultTo('disabled');
      });
    });
  })
  .then(function () {
    return knex.select('*').from('offers');
  })
  .then(function (rows) {
    return Promise.map(rows, function (row) {
      var data = {};
      cols.forEach(function (column) {
        data[column] = row[column + '_old'];
      }, data);
      return knex('offers').where('id', '=', row.id).update(data);
    });
  })
  .then(function () {
    var schema = knex.schema;
    return schema.table('offers', function (table) {
      cols.forEach(function (column) {
        table.dropColumn(column + '_old');
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass valid SQL through knex.raw, so it should be possible to do this:

```
knex.raw(`CREATE TYPE type AS ENUM ('disabled', 'include', 'exclude')`);
knex.raw(`ALTER TABLE test_table ALTER COLUMN test_col DROP DEFAULT`);
knex.raw(`ALTER TABLE test_table ALTER COLUMN test_col TYPE logic USING(test_col::type), ALTER COLUMN test_col SET DEFAULT 'disabled'::logic`);
```

But you will only be able to alter the enumeration through more, similar, knex.raw with DDL. Also note if there is existing data in that column that does not comply to the enumeration the second alter table statement will fail.